# I'm getting a NullPointerException when trying to use a room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm currently trying to use a room database in my app for the first time. My code is supposed to save journal entries to a database when the user adds them, and load the entries into a recyclerview when the app opens. However, I keep getting this error when I open my app:

```
2020-11-25 12:12:56.326 15563-15563/com.google.gradient.red E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.gradient.red, PID: 15563
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.gradient.red.database.JournalDatabase$Companion.getDatabase(JournalDatabase.kt:23)
        at com.google.gradient.red.ui.home.HomeFragment$onViewCreated$1.invokeSuspend(HomeFragment.kt:42)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Here is my code:

```kotlin
package com.google.gradient.red.database

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import com.google.gradient.red.dao.JournalDao
import com.google.gradient.red.entities.Journal

@Database(entities = [Journal::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class JournalDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    companion object{
        var journalDatabase: JournalDatabase? = null

        @Synchronized
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): JournalDatabase{
            if (journalDatabase != null) {
                journalDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                JournalDatabase::class.java,
                "journal.db").build()
            }
            return journalDatabase!!
        }
    }

    abstract fun JournalDao():JournalDao

}
```

Does anyone know what my error means? I think that it's saying that there isn't a database existing there, but I don't know how I could actually solve my issue.

This is my first time using room and I've been trying to figure this out for a while, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please don't reference your code on other platforms, include all your info HERE. remember, this question might help others in future and if your code gets removed from these external sites it becomes useless

Comment: @a_local_nobody I edited my question and put in code from my hastebin. I didn't think about how hastebins get wiped after a month, I apologize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if condition is wrong. It should be

```
if (journalDatabase == null) {
    journalDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context,
    JournalDatabase::class.java,
    "journal.db").build()
}
return journalDatabase!!
```